# Handling 2 arrays with difficult condition. [ PHP ]

Tags: php, arrays, loops, cakephp, select

> The Situation:
>   This is like a loaning process where I can borrow money of a **specific limit or amount**.

So, here.

```
<label> Select Limit </label>
<select id="select_limit">
    <option value="100"> $100 </option>
    <option value="500"> $500 </option>
</select>
```

Now, after I select the **$100** option, I will be prompted, with how much of the $100 I want to cash out,

```
<input type="text" value="100" id="how_much" />
```

The original value for the prompt is the limit I selected, so I want to cash out the whole **$100**.

Now, the `select_limit` should now look like this,

```
<select id="select_limit">
    <option value="500"> $500 </option>
</select>
```

The **$100 dollar option** is now gone because I cash it out **whole**.

That part is easy, here's the problem.
I want to cash out **$300** from the **$500** dollar option. What I want is for `<option value="500"> $500 </option>` to still show from the options because I still have the remaining **$200** to borrow.

**BUT I CAN'T GET IT TO WORK**

> DATABASE:

```
.---------------------.    .---------------------------.
|LIMITS               |    |CASHED OUTS                |
+---------------------+    +---------------------------+
| id    | amount      |    | id  | limits_id  |  amount|
+-------+-------------+    +-----+------------+--------+
| 1     | 100         |    | 1   | 1          | 100    |
+-------+-------------+    +-----+------------+--------+
| 2     | 500         |    | 2   | 2          | 300    |
+-------+-------------+    +-----+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Just a tip.. if you're planning on doing any calculations with these numbers I would recommend you use integers and multiply everything by 100.

Comment: No, These are just dummy data.